# Proper x axis scale with years only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a grid with two plots, each one consist of two time series of mean values: one come from an elaboration with R `df5` the other one `mmzep` is not (I received this dataset already calculated).

```
library(dplyr) 
library(lubridate)
df5 <- data.frame(df$Date, df$Price)
colnames(df5)<- c("date","price")
df5$date <- as.Date(df5$date,"%Y/%m/%d")
df5$price<- as.numeric(gsub(",",".",df5$price))
colnames(mmzep)<- c("date","Mar","Apr")
```

Then, I created other two dfs from `df5` , I tried to group in only one df, but I was not able to do it.

```
meanM <- df5 %>%
          mutate(Month = month(date), Year = year(date)) %>%
          filter(month(df5$date) %in% 3 & year(df5$date) %in% 2010:2019) %>%
          group_by(Year, Month)  %>%
          summarise_all(list(mean=mean,  sd=sd), na.rm=TRUE) %>%
          na.omit()

   Year Month date_mean     price_mean date_sd    price_sd 
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>             <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1  2010     3 2010-03-23         1082.    5.48        685.
2  2012     3 2012-03-27          858.    2.74        333.
3  2015     3 2015-03-16          603.    8.86        411.
4  2017     3 2017-03-15          674.    9.65        512.
5  2018     3 2018-03-16          318.    9.09        202.
6  2019     3 2019-03-14          840.    9.42        329.

meanA <- df5 %>%
          mutate(Month = month(date), Year = year(date)) %>%
          filter(month(df5$date) %in% 4 & year(df5$date) %in% 2010:2019) %>%
          group_by(Year, Month)  %>%
          summarise_all(list(mean=mean, sd=sd), na.rm=TRUE) %>%
          na.omit()

   Year Month date_mean     price_mean date_sd    price_sd 
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>             <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1  2010     4 2010-04-18          361.    9.00        334.
2  2011     4 2011-04-14          527.    8.36        312.
3  2012     4 2012-04-15          726.    8.80        435.
4  2013     4 2013-04-16          872.    8.50        521.
5  2014     4 2014-04-09          668.    5.34        354.
6  2015     4 2015-04-15          689.    8.80        436.
7  2017     4 2017-04-15          806.    8.80        531.
8  2018     4 2018-04-15          727.    8.80        291.
9  2019     4 2019-04-15          600.    8.94        690.

#mmzep
date   Mar   Apr 
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2010  793.  540 
 2  2011  650   378.
 3  2012  813.  612.
 4  2013  755.  717 
 5  2014  432.  634 
 6  2015  474.  782.
 7  2016  590   743.
 8  2017  544.  628 
 9  2018  249.  781 
10  2019  547.  393
```

I plot the dfs

```
g5 = ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=meanM, aes(x = (Year), y = (price_mean)),size = 3, colour="gray40") +
  geom_point(data=mmzep, aes(x= (date), y=(Mar)), size =3, colour = "red") +
  geom_line(data=meanM, aes(group = 1, x = (Year), y = (price_mean)), colour="gray40") +  
  geom_line(data=mmzep, aes(x = (date), y = (Mar)), colour="red") +  
  stat_smooth(data=meanM,aes(group = 1, x = (Year), y = (price_mean)), 
              method = "lm", size = 1, se = FALSE, formula = y ~ x, 
              colour = "black") +
  stat_smooth(data=mmzep, aes(x = (date), y = (Mar)), 
              method = "lm", size = 1, se = FALSE, formula = y ~ x,
              colour = "red3") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 1500))  +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "lines"),
        plot.margin = margin(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, "cm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0.25, unit = "cm")),
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 0.25, unit = "cm"))) +
  labs(y = expression(March), 
       x = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10), 
        axis.title = element_text(size=10))
```

I plot g5 and g6 in the same way, than the grid, to obtain this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29X7G.png)

As you can see the x axis is not correct, I tried `scale_x_date(breaks="year", labels=date_format("%Y"))` , `scale_x_discrete(labels=c("2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019"))`, `scale_x_continuous` in different ways.
I also tried `mmzep$date <- as.Date(mmzep$date,"%Y")` but I saw the R needs a day (in my case a day and a month?) `mmzep$date <- as.Date(paste("01", mmzep$date, sep="/"), "%d/%m/%Y")` , but R substitutes the years with NA. I think that the errors is in the the way R see the date in `mmzep`, but I don't understand how can I made R recognized the correct object.

Anyone have any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2010:2019, labels = as.character(2010:2019))`

Comment: @AllanCameron thank you! this works perfectly! I am sorry for the delay of my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. In your data, your year values are stored as type `double`. This tells `ggplot` that you have a continuous variable. If you want to leave your data as is, then the solution is

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2010, 2020, 2)) 
# or something else that expressly lists the years you want to see on the axis.
```

You cannot use `scale_x_date` without your year data being converted to a date. You can do that with, for example

```
MeanM$Year <- as.Date(paste(MeanM$Year, "01", "01", sep = "/"))
```

Then you can use
+ scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y")

Or you can convert your years into discrete data with `factor`. You cannot use `scale_x_discrete` on a continuous variable.

```
MeanM$Year <- factor(MeanM$Year)
```

And then use

```
+ scale_x_discrete()
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! I apologise for this delayed answer. I am quite new in using R so I think I understand where the error was! I tried all the three solutions. The first and the second ones works without problems. When I tried the third one maybe I made some mistakes because R give me this error `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?` and both the smooth and the geom_line of `mmzep` only get lost. I  substitute `x = factor(Year)` in the code (geom_line and stat_smooth positions) but the error still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach tested on `MeanM` without using `mmzep` which we do not have data. The issue is that as you are using multiple geom the functions are adding strange labels to axis. Changing all x-axis variables to factor can alleviate the issue. In the case of `mmzep` with `aes(x= (date),..)` also be careful on formating the date as year with a code like this `aes(x= factor(format(date,'%Y'))` so that all labels fit well into axis. Here the code:

```
#Code
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=meanM, aes(x = factor(Year), y = (price_mean)),size = 3, colour="gray40") +
  geom_line(data=meanM, aes(group = 1, x = factor(Year), y = (price_mean)), colour="gray40") +  
  stat_smooth(data=meanM,aes(group = 1, x = factor(Year), y = (price_mean)), 
              method = "lm", size = 1, se = FALSE, formula = y ~ x, 
              colour = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 1500))  +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "lines"),
        plot.margin = margin(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, "cm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0.25, unit = "cm")),
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 0.25, unit = "cm"))) +
  labs(y = expression(March), 
       x = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10), 
        axis.title = element_text(size=10))
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
meanM <- structure(list(Year = c(2010L, 2012L, 2015L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L
), Month = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), date_mean = c("23/03/2010", 
"27/03/2012", "16/03/2015", "15/03/2017", "16/03/2018", "14/03/2019"
), price_mean = c(1082L, 858L, 603L, 674L, 318L, 840L), date_sd = c(5.48, 
2.74, 8.86, 9.65, 9.09, 9.42), price_sd = c(685L, 333L, 411L, 
512L, 202L, 329L), Year2 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2010", 
"2012", "2015", "2017", "2018", "2019"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```